# Not understanding function and how it is called from Functional Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just started reading [Functional JavaScript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028857.do) and immediately was introduced to a function that I don't understand:

```
function splat(fun) {
  return function(array) {
    return fun.apply(null, array);
  };
}

var addArrayElements = splat(function(x, y) { return x + y });

addArrayElements([1, 2]);
//=> 3
```

How does `splat(function(x, y) { return x + y })` work. It's called with the array `[1,2]`, but it seems like the anonymous function inside the call to `splat` takes two parameters, not one array.

Putting `console.log(fun)` on line 2 of this code shows that `fun` is the entirety of the anonymous `function(x, y) { return x + y }`. `console.log(array)` after `return function(array) {` shows that array is `[1, 2]`. Where does `array` come from then?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be simpler to see how this function would have been written without using the `.apply` method:

```
function splat(fun) {
  return function(array) {
    return fun(array[0], array[1]);
  };
}
```

First you call splat, passing it a function:

```
var add = function(x,y){ return x + 1 };
var ff  = splat(add);
```

At this point, ff refers to the `function(array)` function, meaning its an one-argument function. The private variable `fun` refers to the `add` function.

Now, you call ff passing its one argument

```
ff([1,2]);
```

and it uses the values in the array to call `fun` with two arguments

```
return fun(array[0], array[1]);
```

The only difference between this and the real example is that the `apply` method lets you work with any argument array length instead of hardcoding a specific length (2) like I did.

Comment: Hi this is really helpful. _The only difference between this and the real example is that the apply method lets you work with any argument array length instead of hardcoding a specific leength (2) like I did._ But wouldn't that be limited to the number of parameters in the passed function with the parameter list `(x, y)`.  Doing `console.log(addArrayElements([1, 2, 6, 8, 5]));
`, is still just going to get me `3`. So it only works with arrays with lengths of 2? [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/inebeq/1/edit)

Comment: @JSBIN: It really does work with any number of arguments, Its just that the extra arguments get ignored because you aren't giving them a name. You don't need to use apply to check this - just pass extra arguments and see what happens: `add(1,2,3,4,5)`.

Comment: Sorry, linked the wrong jsbin before. [On this JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/isacez/1/edit) I get `3` in the console. Do you mean give them a name in the parameter list of `addArrayElements`? That seems to defeat the purpose a little bit, to have to know the number of arguments..

Comment: @thomas: Ah, now I see your question. I was just trying to say that `splat` works with functions of any arity so you can pass `function(x,y,z){ return x + y + z}` and it will receive the 3 arguments just as well (assuming the array has at leas length 3). On the other side, if you want to be able to have the summation function itself handle a variable number of arguments then you need to learn how to use the `arguments` special variable to get the unnamed function arguments.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Any ideas on how I could use the `arguments` variable to do what you describe?

Comment: @thomas: `function(){ var sum = 0; for(var i=0; i< arguments.length; i++){ sum += arguments[i] } return sum; }`.   Its essentially jsu an array but with [caveats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Answer (score 2):

```
addArrayElements = function(array) { fun.apply(null, array); };
```

BUT

it has a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28programming%29) whereby the variable context of its containing scope (that of the `splat` function that created the anonymous function) remains visible and accessible.

In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects that can be referenced and passed as arguments or, as in this case, through the closure mechanism.

**Edit: about JavaScript and scope**

In most languages, variables are, by default, local to the scope they're defined in (which usually is a function's local symbol table). By contrast, in JavaScript a variable is local only if it is defined using the `var` keyword; otherwise, the symbol will be looked back in the chain of the containing scopes, up to the implicit root object (which in the case of web browsers is `window`. I.e.,

```
function foo() { someVar = "bar"; }

foo();
alert(someVar); // shows "bar"
```

Not being restricted to the local scope, the symbol has been (purposely or not) leaked to the root scope.

Taking it one step further:

```
function foo() { 
    var baz = function() { 
        someVar = "bar"; 
    };
    baz();
}

foo();
alert(someVar); // shows "bar"
```

However, if you declare someVar within foo:

```
function foo() { 
    var someVar;
    var baz = function() { 
        someVar = "bar"; 
    };
    baz();
    alert("someVar in foo=" + someVar); // shows "bar"
}

foo();
alert("someVar in root=" + window.someVar); // shows "undefined"
```

Note that in this last version I needed to use window.someVar instead of just someVar because someVar never got defined as a variable in the root scope nor as a property of the root object, which caused an error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you tell me exactly what the "variable context of its containing scope" is?

Comment: See last edit. For more details about scope, [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_scope#Function_scope).

Answer (score 2):

```
//Every time we call this function, we get another one back
function splat(fun) {
  return function(array) {         // <-- this one will be returned in splat();
    return fun.apply(null, array);
  };
}

//Step one, call splat, pass a function as parameter
var addArrayElements = splat(function(x, y) { return x + y });

/*
  Get back a function that accepts an array, and will execute the function we just passed in on it
*/

// This will call the newly created function, func will be available because it's in a closure
addArrayElements([1, 2]);
```

The last thing is that, even if the anonymous function takes two parameters, we call [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on it so it will bind `array[0] ==> x` and `array[1] ==> y`

Comment: Hi thanks. I have a few questions though. _ Get back a function that accepts an array, and will execute the function we just passed in on it_ : I don't really understand what this means. I don't really see code that it refers to. _// This will call the newly created function, func will be available_ : which newly created function? I've gotten a bit lost here I'm afraid.

Comment: Let's see, *// This will call the newly created function,(...)* it's referring to the function returned by `splat` and stored in `addArrayElements` (see comments on `splat`). And, *//Get back a function that accepts(...)* is referring to what is happening in the line above the comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a *higher order function*. That's a function that takes functions as arguments and returns functions instead of just regular values (though functions *are* "just regular values" in Javascript). In this case:

```
function splat(fun) {
```

`splat` takes a function as its argument...

```
return function(array) {
```

...and returns a new function which takes an array...

```
return fun.apply(null, array);
```

...and when called calls the first `fun` function with the array `.applied` as its arguments.

So `splat` takes one function which expects several parameters and wraps it in a function which takes an array of parameters instead. The name "splat" comes from languages like Ruby, where a `*` (a "splat" or "squashed bug") in the parameter list of a function accumulates an arbitrary number of arguments into an array.

```
var addArrayElements = splat(function(x, y) { return x + y });
```

`addArrayElements` is now basically:

```
function (array) {
    // closed over variable:
    // var fun = function(x, y) { return x + y }
    return fun.apply(null, array);
}
```

Here this is realized by a *closure*, which *closes over* and "preserves" the original `fun` passed to `splat` in the new returned function.

Comment: _...and returns a new function which takes an array..._ :where does this array come from? Thanks very much for your help

Comment: You supply the array when you call the function! It's a regular function declaration, declaring that the function *takes an array as argument*.

Answer (score 0):

a more functional approach uses bind(), which is short enough you don't really need splat anymore, and it's always nice to eliminate closures:

```
var addArrayElements = Function.apply.bind( function(x, y) { return x + y } , null );

addArrayElements([1, 2]); // === 3
```

Comment: Thank you. Why is this more functional? Why is it nice to eliminate closures? I don't really fully grasp their practical potential, as I don't even really fully understand them. But I never heard that it is nice to eliminate them. Thanks again.

Comment: closures are bad mmmkaay? they prevent garbage collection, resulting in higher ram use than pure functions, and usually with slower performance. they also prevent you from re-using a function in some other application on different data or in another module. Closures also make the function's activation envelope longer and take more time to instantiate and resolve even local variable names. bottom line: you should always try to avoid closures when using functional programming.